# internal server error in android with django server

Tags: android, django, post, django-rest-framework, retrofit2

my python code in django is:

```
@csrf_exempt
def login(request):
data = {'a': '1'}
if request.method == 'POST':
form=login_form(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
f = form.cleaned_data
if sign_in.objects.filter(username=f['user'], password=hashlib.md5(f['pas'].encode()).hexdigest()):
return JsonResponse(data)
```

and in android:

```
   ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClinet.GetClinet().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<String> call = apiInterface.GetHome_call("x","y");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

this code work in postman and recive: 
{
    "a": "1"
}

but when run in android. recive internal sever error!

and I work on localhost.

Comment: show me ApiClinet code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error must either be in your ApiClient Code or else check your @POST("") correctly , you need to put forward slash at it's end like this: @POST("login/").

Hope this helps,If not please update your question with the Client Code .

Comment: Tank you solved my problem but why PHP server don't need slash?

Comment: I am not sure about it but may be the way the url ends , django urls don't follow any extension like php does!!! This might be a reason.